# What are the Oracle data dictionary views which store metadata about Table Types and Object Types?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I want to find a Table Type is declared as table of object_type. These types are standalone SQL types (not private to any PL/SQL packages or procedures).

I know we can get Object type metadata information from `all_type_attrs` data dictionary view. But couldn't find the view that connects the 
table type and its corresponding object type.

Comment: How is this question connected to Java language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data dictionary view `user_coll_types` (also `all_coll_types`, `dba_coll_types`) which has the information you need. The `elem_type_name` column has the object type, and the `type_name` gives you the collections defined as TABLE OF that type.

So this query will help you:

```
select type_name as table_type_name, coll_type
from user_coll_types 
where elem_type_name = 'APC_T'
/
```

Comment: I m sorry , i m not getting the expected results. I have queried the tables user_coll_types, dba_coll_types,all_coll_types using type_name=tbltype_name. Correct me if i'm wrong.
this what i did ,

create type emp_obj_type as object ( emp_id number ,emp_name varchar2(10));

create emp_tbl_type is table of emp_obj_type;

select * from some_table where tbltype_name='emp_tbl_type' and subObject_type_name='emp_obj_type'; 

'some_table' is what i'm looking for , please help

Answer (score 0):

As APC says, view is called ALL_COLL_TYPES (DBA/USER versions exist also).

Note that Oracle stores identifier names in uppercase unless quoted.

```
CREATE TYPE emp_obj_type AS OBJECT (
   emp_id NUMBER,
   emp_name VARCHAR2 (10));
/   

CREATE TYPE emp_tbl_type IS TABLE OF emp_obj_type;
/

SELECT type_name, elem_type_name
FROM   all_coll_types
WHERE  type_name = 'EMP_TBL_TYPE'
AND    elem_type_name = 'EMP_OBJ_TYPE';
```